# shopify custom liquid section show blank when added via theme editor into an existing page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I created a "custom liquid" section with following code

```
<ul>
{% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
<li class="{{ product_type | handleize }}">
{{ product_type | link_to_type }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It suppose to show a list of product type name as link. But I see nothing. However, when I simply add text into the "Custom Liquid" section, I see it in the page when I add the liquid custom section in the theme's visual editor.

I am using the Free OS2.0 theme
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code will only work on Collection page as it is based on **collection** object. Homepage and other product pages does not have access to collection object directly. However, you can use **collections** object to get a specific collection.

**Show Type on Collection Page**

```
{% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
  {{ product_type | link_to_type }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Show Type for all collections on any page**

```
{% for collection in collections %}
    {% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
        {{ product_type | link_to_type }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Show Type for specific collection on any page**

```
{% for product_type in collections['collection-handle'].all_types %}
  {{ product_type | link_to_type }}
{% endfor %}
```

[Collection Object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/collection#collection-all_types)

[Collections Object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#collections)

Comment: You mentioned "Homepage and other product pages does not have access to collection object directly." do you know the way to enable the collection object access for a page so I can use the object in that page's liquid template? I haven't found a related article about this.

Comment: @Ezeewei I have already mentioned that in my answer. The bottom 2 code snippets that use **collections object** can be used on any Shopify page.